# How to transform function to lambda function

Tags: c++, function, lambda

I have function:

```
FARPROC PUDSClass::getFunction(LPSTR szName)
{
    if(handleDLL == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return GetProcAddress(handleDLL, szName);
}
```

I am trying to rewrite it as lambda function.

```
FARPROC lambda_decToStrHex = [&](LPSTR szName)
{
    if (handleDLL == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return GetProcAddress(handleDLL, szName);
};
```

But I get error of inconsistent types "int" and "int (attribute(stdcall)*)()".

If I write it like this, it works ok:

```
auto getFunction = [&](LPSTR szName)
{
    return GetProcAddress(handleDLL, szName);
};
```

From what I understood, lambda cannot handle return NULL or GetProcAddress(), but why can a normal function do so?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be able to handle `return NULL;`??? Sidenote: You should prefer C++ *keywords* (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`).

Comment: Please provide descriptions for everything not in C/C++ standards in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FARPROC lambda_decToStrHex = ...;
```

This will create a variable `lambda_decToStrHex`, it's type is `FARPROC`, which, according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-callwindowproca), is defined as

```
int (FAR WINAPI * FARPROC) ()
```

It is a function returning int and accepting no parameters. This simply doesn't match the type of your lambda.

If at all, you need a function pointer of correct type the lambda can decay to, a function accepting a C string and returning a `FARPROC` pointer (in short: pointer to function returning function pointer):

```
FARPROC (*lambda_decToStrHex)(LPSTR) = ...;
```

Solely: *Your* lambda *cannot* decay to a function pointer, as it has a non-empty closure:

```
... = [&](LPSTR name) { /* ... */ };
//     ^                    ^ uses dllHandle, which thus gets part of closure
```

So all that remains is assigning the lambda to a variable thetype of your lambda, which you get by `auto`.

---

*Edit: `return NULL;`:*

'Lambda' is a red herring here, it is not an issue of lambdas, but of any function having deduced return type (`auto f() { ... }`). `NULL` typically is defined as `(void*)0`, (but can look differently as well), so you get two different return types (`void*` and `FARPROC`) at the two exit points of the (in this case) lambda. Which return type should now be deduced?

At very first, you shouldn't be using `NULL` at all any more, it is a *macro* coming from C, whereas C++ provides a *keyword* for: `nullptr`. Solely, it won't solve the issue, as it has it's own type (`std::nullptr_t`) which still differs from `FARPROC`. A cast then can solve the issue (that actually would work with the macro as well):

```
return static_cast<FARPROC>(nullptr);
```

Now both exit points have the same return type and we are fine. A trailing return type achieves the same:

```
[&](LPSTR) -> FARPROC { ... }
```

`nullptr` automatically decays to correct pointer type (so you don't need a cast); `NULL` macro, without a cast and depending on how being defined, *can* (but needn't) fail, though.

Another solution would be one single, well defined exit point:

```
[&](LPSTR)
{
    FARPROC function = nullptr;
    if(dllHandle)
        function = get();
    return function;
}
```

Why did it work with the normal function then? Well, you explicitly specified the return type (`FARPROC f(...)`), which is equivalent to having a trailing return type. Additionally, the fact that it compiled and the error message:

```
"int" and "int (attribute(stdcall)*)()"
 ^^^
```

reveal that your compiler obviously defines `NULL` without the `void*` cast:

```
#define NULL 0
```

or similar – and `0` literal decays to null pointer as well...

Comment: Wonderful explanation; so all I do is use 'auto' instead of 'FARPROC'. But if I have 'if (handleDLL == NULL) return null', I still get error, which I described in question (inconsistent types). Why is it working ok in normal function, but in lambda function I get this error?

Comment: `[&](LPSTR)
{
    if (dllHandle)
        return get(dllHandle);
    return nullptr;
}` would be fine too (I would probably write it `return dllHandle ? get(dllHandle) : nullptr;` BTW). Return types don't have to be identical, but all should be compatible with the first return type encounter.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specify the return type `FARPROC` in normal function, `NULL` (`0`, which is `int` type) will implicitly convert to `FARPROC` type (which is `int (attribute(stdcall)*)()`).

You can using using `->` to specify the return type with lambda:

```
auto lambda_decToStrHex = [&](LPSTR szName) -> FARPROC
{
    if (handleDLL == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return GetProcAddress(handleDLL, szName);
};
```

Comment: Although `nullptr` indeed should be preferred over `NULL`, it still has it's own type: `std::nullptr_t`. Thus you still get inconsistent return types without an explicit cast in first approach...